# Dart: Why does the following code compiles in strong mode?

Tags: class, inheritance, dart, static-typing

```
void main(){
  new C(new A()); // This gives no warning or error
  new D(new A()); // This gives an error

}
class A{}

class B extends A{}

class C {
  B b;
  C(A bb){    this.b = bb;   }
}

class D {  
  B b; 
  D(this.b); 
}
```

In both statements in main function I give as a parameter  an instance of type A. If I am not wrong both statements should give an error or warning in Strong mode, however only the second gives an error:  *Type check failed: new A()(A) is not of type B*

[Image showing the code compiled from https://dartpad.dartlang.org/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pcipz.png)

I just started learning dart language and I couldn't find in the documentation an explanation for this case. Does anybody know why  this is happening?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you made a typo in your `C` constructor. Do you mean:

```dart
class C {
  B b;
  C(B/*not A*/ bb){    this.b = bb;   }
}
```

Comment: No, actually the error message should be in this line : `this.b = bb;` because the type of b is B and bb is A.  I think I found the answer here:.             _Because down-assignments may be valid and Dart is optimistic that you know what you’re doing, we make them pass static checking too._  What I am doing there is a  down-assignment.  [https://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/](https://www.dartlang.org/articles/why-dart-types/) Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: That's it. It's a _implicit downcast_. There's an issue to [add a flag to disable it](http://dartbug.com/26583)